# $M/Erlang-2/1$ number of customers distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Is there a known closed-form distribution of the number of customers in a $M/Erlang-2/1$ system with service rate $2/\mu$ and $\lambda$ as the arrival rate to the system?
I wonder if such a general distribution formula exists for this specific setting. Is working through the recursive procedure yield from the Pollaczek-Khintchine formula the only way about it, or did someone develop a closed-form distribution in the past?

Thanks so much if anyone is familiar with such a formula.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with an $M/Erlang$ distribution, but Wikipedia shows an Erlang distribution, which is just a gamma distribution, and also $M/G/k$, and $M/M/1$ distributions. Are you referring to any of these?

Comment: Thanks, @apelt001. The distribution of the number of customers in the system for $M/G/k$ is not known. The one for $M/M/k$ or $M/M/1$ is known. For the $M/G/1$ system, it is only known in spatial cases. There is a known recursion procedure for the $M/E2/1$ system (a special case of the $M/G/1$). However, I was wondering if there exists a closed-form formula for it. Unfortunately, you can't find it in Wiki.